# Video Playing based upon database time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, jplayer

I am using CodeIgniter framework and JPlayer for playing video. I want video playlist will play based on playlist time in database.

So how to continuously check database time with current time? If time matched then I want start that playlist.

I want to play video according to database time. I have playlist. Playlist contains one or more than one videos. Every Playlist has date and time. So I want to play this playlist(one or more videos) according to date and time of New York time.

I know how to play playlist but I dont know how to check continuously date and time from MySQL database using PHP/JQuery and collect data and play next playlist.

PS: I am using JPlayer for playing videos/playlist. JPlayer Playlist reference: http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with codeigniter, but if I had to do it in .Net I would create a DateTime object and initialize it from the database using SELECT GETDATE() ... now I will run a timer with a frequency of 1 second and do DateTimeObject.AddSecond(1) each time the timer event fires. I will also compare the timeToPlay with the DateTimeObject and if the time matches, I will run the playlist. Hope this helps

Comment: Logic looks right but by using jquery ?